# jquery plugin for background image crossfade slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I wasn't successful with Google search to find a neat JQuery plugin that would allow me to setup a nice background image slideshow. Something like [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/2011/07/supersized-3-2-fullscreen-jquery-slideshow/) or [Vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) plugins... These two are awesome but I would like it to work on individual elements (header, div, ...) and not filling the full browser area. Thanks for the tips!

QUESTION UPDATE:

Let me update my question, since maybe it was not clear what I need.

I do not need standard carousel or image slideshow gallery. There are tons of those but they all work on fixed container/image width. What I need is to have an image in full width of browser window and with fixed height. I need this image to be centered and overflown on both sides of this container. Much like you achieve with `background: url(image.jpg) center top scroll no-repeat;`. If browser resizes I want this image to stay centered, just more of it is visible. Then I would like to have 4-5 images to form a cross-fading slideshow.

You can check my sample page to see my bg image setup: http://v3krasne.si.bitcloud.nine.ch/

Comment: I think cycle plugin will do the job for you.

Comment: Maybe with a lot of tweaking I could use cycle plugin yes!

Comment: I have managed to get a right result with cycle plugin! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get a desired result with [JQuery Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin.